# c++ - Unable to increment at the end of an if-statement in the for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, vector, increment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h> 

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  //Declaring variables:
  int numberoftestcase=0;
  string words;
  vector<string> holder;
  vector<char> character;
  int counter=0;

  //Allow user inputs a number to declare the size of the vector holder
  cin >> numberoftestcase;

  //Allow user to input words;
  for(int i=0;i<numberoftestcase;i++)
  {
    cin >> words;
    holder.push_back(words);
  }


for(int position=0;position<holder[counter].length();position++)
{
    if(position<holder[counter].length())
    {
        character.push_back(holder[counter].at(position)); 
        cout << character[position] << endl;  
    }
    else
    {
        counter++;
    }
  }

}
```

I want to come up with a program which is able to

1. Input a number to declare the test cases. Like if input 4, then it means that there are 4 test cases going to input(Done)
2. It could split a string into characters and store in a vector.(Partly done)

There is a problem for target 2(Refer to the second for-loop). I found that my program is unable to increment the counter. That is, once the holder[0] is done, it leaves the for loop and end program. It will not go to holder[1],holder[2] etc.

Why is it like so and How to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: debug, check the values, you'll generally find it is doing exactly what you told it to do. If it's confusing, you can convert the for loop into an equivalent while loop, so it's easier to set breakpoints at specific places. Maybe you are confusing position in the array with a value in the array?

Comment: You need a second for loop for counter = 0 to numberoftestcase

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yes, I am a bit confusing. Cause I don't understand why the current method is wrong. I think my logic is correct"If the position equals to the length of the holder[i], then counter++". This should work but the truth is not working. I don't understand why

Comment: @willll I tried to do it like below. But it still not working

Comment: for(int counter = 0; counter<numberoftestcase;counter++)
{
for(int position=0;position<holder[counter].length();position++)
{
    if(position<holder[counter].length())
    {
        character.push_back(holder[counter].at(position)); 
        cout << character[position] << endl;  
    }
}
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two nested `for` loops.  One iterating through the words in holder, one iterating through the characters in a word.  I would write it as:

```
    for (const auto& word: holder)
    {
        for (const auto ch: word)
        {
            character.push_back(ch);
            cout << character.back();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Can you explain why use "&" symbol in "const auto& word: holder" but no the & symbol in "const auto ch: word"? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ricky: The `&` means "reference".  `word` is a (reference to) a `std::string`. `std::string` is a complex object.  Without the the reference, `word` would have to be (expensively) copied from the vector.  On the other hand, `ch` will be a `char` object, which is about as lightweight as you can imagine; as such, it is cheaper to copy the char, rather than maintain a reference (although a good compiler may well optimize to the same machine code anyway).